# [karate][standalone] Error : could not find or read file

Tags: karate

I am only using the latest standalone karate jar to test my API on a docker container configured with JRE and I don't have any Java code.

Currently on one of my features, i have this : `read('file.json')`, 
and it works fine when the resource file is on the same directory than the feature file. I know that it is recommended to do this way.

But if i also want to have a central directory with all resource files to avoid duplicatas,
it doesn't work even with this command :
`read('classpath:directory/file.json')`

The error is the following :

> "[com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: could not find or read file: xxx, prefix: CLASSPATH"

I even tried without success to set a classpath on the command line when running the jar :
`java -cp $CLASSPATH . -jar ~/karate.jar`

My question: Is it possible to set a Prefix on Karate with the standalone jar to be able to easily  read any file from other directories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the `file:` prefix, instead of `classpath:` it will support absolute or even relative paths from current working directory.

Version 0.8.0 had some bugs with file path handling especially on Windows. So try 0.9.0.RC4 if you get stuck - but do provide feedback on it if possible anyways.

Comment: Tried this solution on linux and it doesent seam to work, did I understood well how this works? https://i.imgur.com/HfaiaLp.png @peter-thomas

Comment: @DusanGligoric sorry unable to make out anything, please refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue