# [karate][standalone] how to add sikulixapi.jar to classpath by default using karate-config.js?

Tags: karate, sikuli, sikuli-x

```
Karate version: 0.9.5.RC3
IDE : Visual Studio Code 1.38.1
OS: Windows 10 Ent
```

I have downloaded the zip and was running Native Automation example with SikuliX using the karate standalone jar.

Now to execute the tests I need to use below command
`java -cp karate.jar;sikulixapi.jar com.intuit.karate.Main %*`

Instead of this, I want to use the `karate-config.js` file to specify the classpath in which `sikulixapi.jar` plus some other jar is already present.

Also, one should be able to run tests directly using the below command.
`java -jar karate.jar calc.feature`
or using the `Karate Runner` plugin in Visual Studio Code.

BTW a great thanks to the creators of `KarateDSL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Setting the classpath is such a fundamental operation that it has to be done when the JVM is started. The recommended approach is you edit a batch file to do this, see this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398958/143475

There are some hacks you can try such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/252967/143475