# not able to run "karate-demo" runners in VSCode because of karate-core classes cannot be resolved

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, karate

I've downloaded zip file (instead of repo cloning) from Karate´s gitlab home page (0.9.6 version) and also configured VS Code with java recommended stuff, but some imports are failing ...

This one from DemoLogModifier.java when trying

```
import com.intuit.karate.http.HttpLogModifier;
```

[DemoLogModifier.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6O45.png)

With the error

```
The import com.intuit.karate.http.HttpLogModifier cannot be resolvedJava(268435846)
```

When using Intellij these errors are not there

I have 19 extensions installed

- Cloudfoundry Manifest YML Support
- Concourse CI Pipeline Editor
- Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support
- Debugger for Java
- ESLint
- Java Extension Pack
- Java Test Runner
- Karate Runner
- Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
- Maven for Java
- Project Manager for Java
- Python
- SonarLint
- Spring Boot Dashboard
- Spring Boot Extension Pack
- Spring Boot Tools
- Spring Initializr Java Support
- Visual Studio IntelliCode
- XML

This is my settings json

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-11",
          "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home",
          "sources" : "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.9.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/src.zip",
          "javadoc" : "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api",
          "default":  true
         }
      ],
      "maven.executable.preferMavenWrapper": false,
      "maven.pomfile.autoUpdateEffectivePOM": true,
      "maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true,
      "java.maven.downloadSources": true
}
```

And this is my .zshrc

```
##JAVA
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export M2_HOME=/Users/agilcoto/Work/apache-maven-3.6.3
export MAVEN_HOME=$M2_HOME
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
export PATH=$PATH:$M2
```

Any clue? what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

The ZIP release is intended for those not familiar with Java. I suggest you stick with Maven if you intend to a) use Java interop or b) use custom hooks or implement a log modifier etc

You *can* add custom Java compiled code to the classpath in the "standalone" option if you know what you are doing, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398958/143475

Comment: Thanks Peter. I just zipped the repo and unzipped locally. All other folders are ok, just karate-demo is failing

Comment: I mean, that error is prompted by VSCode Interface without doing anything

Comment: @Ton I have no other ideas - hopefully someone else or a VS code expert can help here

Comment: @Ton can you try the demo project here and confirm if it works in VSCode.  https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle  If it does I would do some process of elimination between your project and this one to hone in on the issue.  Generally if you can make Maven, Gradle and Karate.jar work from the command line it should work from VSCode as it is effectively just constructing a command line call for convenience.  Please let us know what you find out.

Comment: Thank you @CaptainKirk I have downloaded your repo zip, unzipped and copied 'karate-demo' folder from karate directory. This is now the `ls`command output "bin, build, build.gradle, gradle, gradle.properties, gradlew, gradlew.bat, karate-demo, mvnw, mvnw.cmd, pom.xml, README.md, src" and no error shown in VSCode. "Project And External Dependencies" at "JAVA PROJECTS" section shows: "/Users/agilcoto/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.intuit.karate/karate-apache/0.9.6/9c030562ac554d5360bb5ce5e55f53fb6e821dd9/karate-apache-0.9.6.jar" ... [more on next comment] ...

Comment: The rest of karate* stuff at JAVA PROJECTS: /Users/agilcoto/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.intuit.karate/karate-core/0.9.6/9af3ab1a8ce3f968da760b7faa983ea97bf49db3/karate-core-0.9.6.jar
/Users/agilcoto/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.intuit.karate/karate-gatling/0.9.6/4a2116f03c2533a6d071ce01bf0a95ffa7bd7d6e/karate-gatling-0.9.6.jar
/Users/agilcoto/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.intuit.karate/karate-junit5/0.9.6/2217d460f8dfc4f5e8499bceaefe8fdedd24832/karate-junit5-0.9.6.jar

Comment: And last one ... /Users/agilcoto/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.intuit.karate/karate-mock-servlet/0.9.6/e85d957f82829820f7aa0ae11e74a30048786754/karate-mock-servlet-0.9.6.jar

Comment: Is it enough with just copying 'karate-demo' folder into project "root" folder? I am getting this warning in the DemoLogModifier.java file ... `DemoLogModifier.java is not on the classpath of project karate-maven-gradle-master, it will not be compiled to a .class fileJava(32)`

Comment: I have found that same "Project And External Dependencies" at JAVA PROJECTS section for `karate` project is returning version 0.9.2 instead of version 0.9.6 for karate* jars ... /Users/agilcoto/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.intuit.karate/karate-core/0.9.2/aebafaddcc80d7e72a8f235109cf4730ac8d92d9/karate-core-0.9.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to get to the root cause ...

VSCode, with my current configuration, it is using `build.gradle` file by default
So, I have to make several updates to it

`karate-demo/build.gradle`

```
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    springVersion = '4.3.8.RELEASE'
    gradleVersionProperty = '4.1'
    karateVersion = '0.9.6'
    masterThoughtVersion = '3.8.0'
    activeMqVersion = '5.15.2'
}
```

The update above is the `karateVersion` value, from `0.9.2` to `0.9.6`

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
runtime 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.196'
```

The update above are the `commons-codec` and `javax` modules, that weren't configured

Also I needed to add the `commons-codec` module to `karate-demo/pom.xml` file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Finally there are still issues with standard sonarlint best practices at two files

`/Users/agilcoto/Work/scratches/karate/karate-netty/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Main.java`

The sonarlint extension is throwing the error `Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from XX to the 15 allowed.sonarlint(java:S3776)` for two methods:

1. main: 17
2. call: 18

`/Users/agilcoto/Work/scratches/karate/karate-netty/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/ProxyServerSslMain.java`

The sonarlint extension is throwing the error `Add at least one assertion to this test case.sonarlint(java:S2699)` for the method `testProxy`

Final `settings.json` VSCode conf file must include, if sonarlint is enabled, this property

```
  "sonarlint.rules": {
    "java:S3776": {
      "level": "off"
    },
    "java:S2699": {
      "level": "off"
    }   }
```