# "Class not found" when runing feature with karate.jar

Tags: java, classpath, karate, graalvm, graaljs

I have a feature that execute a function from a Java class. So for this reason I use this command to get the class and create a new instance:

[image]

When I run this feature with maven (mvn test -Dtest...) everything is okay. The problem is when I run this feature with karate standalone jar, karate can't find the RCNUtils class.

**Error:**

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class utilities.RCNUtils is not allowed or does not exist.
```

[image]

**GraalJS error:** https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/FAQ.md#typeerror-access-to-host-class-commyexamplemyclass-is-not-allowed-or-does-not-exist

---

I think it's a classpath problem but I have tried with a lot of differents paths and commands to execute the jar, and nothing works.

I don't know if this is a known issue or if there is a karate example using utilities classes and executed with karate.jar

> I tested this problem with differents Karate versions. Actually I'm using Karate 1.1.0

**Some of the options I have tried with no results:**

1. Use -w / --workdir param to change working directory with no results
2. Use java -cp instead of java -jar to set classpath following:
   [Unable to use read('classpath:') when running tests with standalone karate.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398742/unable-to-use-readclasspath-when-running-tests-with-standalone-karate-jar)
3. Use -Dkarate.config.dir param

Note: I don't think it's a security problem because if I try to get "RCNUtils.java" file with "karate.read()" or "read()" in the same feature, it works. I think because I can put the path to the file. The problem is that I can't put the path to java class in "Java.type()" method

**Same error here:** [Executing Karate jar with mock using external library Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456840/executing-karate-jar-with-mock-using-external-library-spring-framework/56458094#56458094)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have nothing to suggest except that you follow this process. maybe it is a security thing, I don't know: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I was able to replicate this in a Gradle project -- will open an issue and add a zipped-up sample project.  Probably an easy fix, but I'm lousy at troubleshooting this stuff.